# C# Decoding Win-1251 byte array

Tags: c#

I'm writing a Caesar cipher program but there is a problem with encoding. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
public class CaesarCipher
{
    private string Encode(string text, int k)
    {
        var retVal = "";
        Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
        Encoding utf32 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-32");
        byte[] text1251 = win1251.GetBytes(text);

        for (int i = 0; i < text1251.Length; i++)
        {

            var c = text1251[i];
            var index = (int)c;
            Console.Write(index + "/");
            var codeIndex = (index + k) % 256;
            byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(codeIndex);
            byte[] newbytes = Encoding.Convert(utf32, win1251, bytes);
            Console.Write(codeIndex + "\n");
            retVal += win1251.GetString(newbytes);

        }
        return retVal;
    }
    private string Decode(string text, int k)
    {
        var retVal = "";
        Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
        Encoding utf32 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-32");
        byte[] text1251 = win1251.GetBytes(text);

        for (int i = 0; i < text1251.Length; i++)
        {

            var c = text1251[i];
            var index = (int)c;
            Console.Write(index + "/");
            var codeIndex = (index - k) % 256;
            byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(codeIndex);
            byte[] newbytes = Encoding.Convert(utf32, win1251, bytes);
            Console.Write(codeIndex + "\n");
            retVal += win1251.GetString(newbytes);

        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public string Encrypt(string plainMessage, int key)
        => Encode(plainMessage, key);


    public string Decrypt(string encryptedMessage, int key)
        => Decode(encryptedMessage, key);
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cipher = new CaesarCipher();
        Console.Write("Enter the text: ");
        var message = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter the key: ");
        var secretKey = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter 1 (Encrypt) or 2 (Decrypt): ");
        var message1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (message1 == 1)
        {
            var encryptedText = cipher.Encrypt(message, secretKey);
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted text: {0}", encryptedText);
        }
        if (message1 == 2)
        {
            var encryptedText = cipher.Decrypt(message, secretKey);
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Text: {0}", encryptedText);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

First of all, I need to have character count of 256, so I guessed that using Win-1251 encoding is necessary. I have a problem with converting to and form Win-1251 encoding. If I run this code, I get incorrect conversion with cyrillic characters:

```
Enter the text: абвгд
Enter the key: 3
Enter 1 (Encrypt) or 2 (Decrypt): 1
224/227
225/228
226/229
227/230
228/231
Encrypted text: aaa?c
```

If I remove the "byte[] newbytes = Encoding.Convert(utf32, win1251, bytes);" line and change "retVal += win1251.GetString(**newbytes**);" to "retVal += win1251.GetString(**bytes**);", then I get the following output:

```
Enter the text: абвгд
Enter the key: 3
Enter 1 (Encrypt) or 2 (Decrypt): 1
224/227
225/228
226/229
227/230
228/231
Encrypted text: г   д   е   ж   з
```

This output is correct, however it puts these whitespaces between characters, which shouldn't be there. Is there any way to have correct decryption without whitespaces?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Encoding.Convert function wrong.
It should be

```
        var newbytes = Encoding.Convert(win1251, utf8, bytes);
        retVal += utf8.GetString(newbytes);
```

The function signature is `Convert(srcEncoding, dstEncoding, bytes)` and you had the encodings in opposite order.And then you called `GetString` on the win1251 instead the utf32. I also used utf8 instead of utf32 as I think it is a better option.

Comment: After adding these corrections the output is the same as in the last block of my question, with whitespaces between characters. Is there any way to get rid of those?

Comment: @IwakuraLain I'm not having this problem. I'm guessing it has something to do with your local setting. Can you try [this Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SG60l9)?

Comment: Yeah, this code works perfectly in browser, but in my Visual Studio it still displays extra spaces. What settings do you think might be at fault?

Comment: What is your console encoding? Can you set it to unicode?

Comment: It says it's code page is 866. I tried setting it to unicode but failed, I might have used wrong methods though.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window) worked for me.